# Is the "Translated average" $(T_rf)(x)$ of an $L^1$ function $f$ continuous in $(r,x)$?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\in L^1(m)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^k$. For each $r>0$, $x\in \Bbb{R}^k$, let $B(x,r)$ be the open ball centered at $x$ having radius $r$, and consider
\begin{align}
 (T_rf)(x):= \dfrac{1}{m\left(B(x,r)\right)}\int_{B(x,r)} \left| f(y) - f(x)\right|\, dm(y).
\end{align}
My question is whether the mapping $(r,x)\mapsto (T_rf)(x)$ is continuous/lower-semicontinuous? If so, could you provide a proof/proof outline? Otherwise, could you provide a counterexample?

---

I know that for corresponding averaging function
\begin{align}
(A_rf)(x):= \dfrac{1}{m\left(B(x,r)\right)}\int_{B(x,r)} f\, dm,
\end{align}
it is true that $(r,x)\mapsto (A_rf)(x)$ is continuous, simply by observing that for any sequence $(x_n,r_n)\to (x,r)$, the corresponding indicator functions $\mathbf{1}_{B(x_n,r_n)}\to \mathbf{1}_{B(x,r)}$ everywhere except perhaps on the boundary of $B(x,r)$, which is of measure zero with respect to $m$, and hence $f\cdot \mathbf{1}_{B(x_n,r_n)}\to f\cdot \mathbf{1}_{B(x,r)}$. Also it is easy to see that for large enough $n$, we have $B(x_n,r_n)\subset B(x,r+2)$, which means we have an integrable dominating function, so continuity follows from the dominated convergence theorem.

When I tried to adapt a similar approach for $(T_rf)(x)$, I found that the extra $-f(x)$ term in the integrand makes things very annoying. I tried first of all approximating (relative to $L^1$ norm) $f$ by a continuous $\phi$ of compact support, but I got stuck, and that wasn't too helpful. I would appreciate any help with this.

---

The reason I'm asking this (if anyone is curious) is that in Rudin's RCA, chapter 7, he proves that almost every point of $\Bbb{R}^k$ is a Lebesgue point for $f$, by showing that the function $(Tf)(x):= \limsup\limits_{r\to 0}(T_rf)(x)$ has the property that for every $s>0$, the set $\{Tf>s\}$ is contained in a Lebesgue-measurable subset of measure $0$, hence by completeness of $m$, $\{Tf> s\}$ is itself Lebesgue measurable (and of measure $0$). So, I'm just wondering if we could avoid appealing to completeness of Lebesgue measure to deduce measurability of the set, by trying to prove the stronger statement that $(r,x)\mapsto (T_rf)(x)$ is continuous/lower semicontinuous.

Comment: Consider the function f(x)=1 if x is rational, and f(x)=0 if x is irrational. The local average of Tf(x) = <|f(x)-f(y)|> is 0 if x is irrational, and is 1 if x is rational. Hence, I guess the answer is no.

Comment: @WHLin Thank you for the counterexample. I guess we could generalize this further by taking $E$ to be any Lebesgue-measurable set of zero Lebesgue measure, which is not Borel measurable, because this way, $(T_rf)(x) = \mathbf{1}_E(x)$. Hence, $Tf$ is Lebesgue measurable but not Borel measurable (hence not upper/lower semicontinuous hence not continuous).